# on.exit() callbacks dropped when passing expression to function

Tags: r

I have a function with an `on.exit()` callback, and I want to pass an expression with its own set of callbacks. The second set of callbacks are dropped unexpectedly. Below, `"first_callback"` and `"second_callback"` should both print.

```r
f <- function(expr) {
  on.exit(print("first_callback"), add = TRUE)
  force(expr)
}
f(on.exit(print("second_callback"), add = TRUE))
#> [1] "first_callback"
```

Session info:

```r
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.7

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_4.0.2       htmltools_0.5.0.9000 tools_4.0.2         
 [4] yaml_2.2.1           rmarkdown_2.3        knitr_1.29          
 [7] xfun_0.16            digest_0.6.25        packrat_0.5.0       
[10] rlang_0.4.7          evaluate_0.14
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `second_callback` use of `on.exit` is evaluated in the calling environment, not that of `f`. If you were to exit the current context, then you would see it fire. I'll simulate that by calling `f(...)` from another function (that then exits):

```r
(function() { f(on.exit(print("second_callback"), add = TRUE));})()
# [1] "first_callback"
# [1] "second_callback"
```

Ultimately you want non-standard evaluation of the expression and force it to operate in the current environment. (A good reference is http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html.)

I'm inferring that you expect `second_callback` to fire *first* because of the order you execute the first callback and then the expression. From `?on.exit`:

```
   after: if 'add' is TRUE and 'after' is FALSE, then 'expr' will be
          added on top of the expressions that were already registered.
          The resulting last in first out order is useful for freeing
          or closing resources in reverse order.
```

As such:

```r
f <- function(expr) {
  expr <- substitute(expr)
  on.exit(print("first_callback"), add = TRUE)
  eval(expr, envir = environment())
}

f(on.exit(print("second_callback"), add = TRUE))
# [1] "second_callback"
# [1] "first_callback"
```

Side note, though, is that often expressions passed (lazily) to a function like this ... may be expected to operate in the calling environment/frame, not within the function itself. While this example works, there are other situations where perhaps the call will not work because it expects variables to be present that are not in the current environment.